# Bound the tails of $\exp(- \|x\|^2 / (2\sigma^2))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, statistics, normal-distribution

## Problem

Consider the (multivariate Gaussian density) function
$$
f_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{m/2}\sigma^m}\exp\left(-\frac{\|x\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).
$$
I want to show that there exists a constant $A$ such that
$$
|f_\sigma(x)| \leq \frac{A\sigma}{\|x\|^{m+1}}
$$
for any $\sigma > 0$ and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^m\backslash\{0\}$.

## Attempted Solution

I know I can bound $\exp( -\|x\|^2 / (2\sigma^2) ) \leq 1$, which gives me
$$
|f_\sigma(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{m/2}\sigma^m}.
$$
I could multiply and divide by $\sigma$ but then not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that
$$r^{m+1} e^{-r^2/2} \longrightarrow 0$$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$.
So, this function is bounded by some constant.
Replace $r$ by $\|x\|/\sigma$ to conclude.

Comment: How does it follow that it must be bounded by a constant?

Comment: A continuous function on ${\bf R}_+$ that tends to zero at infinity is bounded. You can compute explicitly the bound by calculating the zero of the derivative.

Comment: Do you mind pointing me to a reference for this?

Comment: For instance $f(r) = 1/r$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and tends to zero at infinity, but it is not bounded.

Comment: Your function is not defined on ${\bf R}_+ = [0,\infty)$.

Comment: This is proven for example in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097515/a-continuous-function-on-a-half-closed-interval?rq=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/features-of-continuous-function?rq=1